# PHP/HTML Form Feeding Blank Entries to MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I am a PHP/MySQL Greenback here, and I have run into an issue with a simple form I am trying to feed into a MySQL database via PHP, that keeps feeding blank entries.

The form is live, connecting and feeding to the DB, however whenever I submit an entry, my confirmation echo's back that it `Connected successfullyINSERT INTO db_name.events (eventname, eventprice, eventabout) VALUES ('', '', '') Works!` even though the values were populated in the HTML form. Then when I log in and check the MySQL Database through PHPmyadmin I can see that it indeed created a new row in the table, but it is blank.

I have spent hours combing the syntax line by line and can't seem to find anything out of place and I have now added a bunch of troubleshooting steps in to try and solve it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

The HTML form is as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="eventtestconnect.php"><table style="border: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;text-align: left">
      <tr>
        <td>Event Name:</td>
        <td><input name="name"></td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td>Event Price:</td>
        <td><input name="price"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Event Description:</td>
        <td><textarea name="description" cols="40" rows="5">
        </textarea></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

And the PHP file that connects to this form is:

```
<?php

// connect to database
$dbhost = '111.111.11.111';
$dbuser = 'db_name';
$dbpass = 'pwpwpw';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';

//select database
mysql_select_db("db_name", $conn);
if ($_POST)
{

// scrub inputs
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']); 
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['price']);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['description']);

// prepare query
$sql = "INSERT INTO db_name.events (eventname, eventprice, eventabout)
 VALUES ('$name', '$price', '$description')"; 

// execute query
mysql_query($sql);

// close connection
mysql_close($conn);
echo $sql;
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help, I have been browsing these forums grabbing help and tips. Seems like a great community!

Comment: Where does the line "INSERT INTO db_name.events (eventname, eventprice, eventabout) VALUES ('', '', '') Works!" come from?

Comment: That's because of the `echo $sql;` line i included at the end of my php so that when I click submit on the form it gives me details from the query. It's for testing to see if data is being pulled from the form or not. @MarkM

Comment: @MikeW When i echo my query right before execution I get the same result as echoing it after the connection to the server has been closed. And echoing errors brings up no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passing in the arguments to `mysql_real_escape_string` in the wrong order. It should be:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'], $conn);
```